# My zsh autocompletion for CDPATH stopped working

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I am using zsh and I always were able to cd right into paths that are part of my CDPATH configuration but, starting a few days ago, the completion stopped working.

```
mbp:~ $ echo $CDPATH
/Users/fcoury/Projects:/Users/fcoury:/Users/fcoury/code
```

CDPATH is still working:

```
mbp:~ $ pwd
/Users/fcoury
mbp:~ $ cd rackapp
~/Projects/rackapp
mbp:rackapp(master) $ pwd
/Users/fcoury/Projects/rackapp
```

But if I do `cd rack` and hit tab, no suggestions appear. Before, it would show all subdirectories of either ~/Projects, ~/code or ~ that would match "rack*".

Any ideas of what could have happened?

Comment: I discovered this just stopped working for me as well. Are you using Oh My ZSH? I am and am wondering if that is the link.

Comment: Yes I am @localshred, but I don't remember updating it...

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
typeset -U path cdpath fpath
```

to the bottom of your .zshrc/.zshenv file, as that worked for me.

Comment: This works, but...why? I'm looking it up, but a bit of explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(cd|pushd):*' tag-order \
'local-directories named-directories path-directories'
```

`path-directories` are directories from `CDPATH`, which the command above adds to zsh's completion for `cd/pushd`. This is from: [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/265547/zsh-cdpath-and-autocompletion).